# Adding new Web Front End. What will stop working?

Tags: 2010, deployment, installation

I have one web server with Central Administration and all SharePoint web applications on it. I want to add new front end.

Will, at any point of adding new new web front end server to existing SharePoint farm, web application on first web server stop working? 
Will users on first SharePoint web application server experience any delays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a second web front end will have no impact on the existing server(s).

But it'll not do anything until it's been added to some kind of Load balancing or if you use it for crawling.

Comment: I'm afraid that, during installation, existing web server will stop working for a moment (maybe IIS reset?). If application stops to work even for a moment i will have >20 angry users on phone :).I'm planing to deal with load balancing later.